# What does “The university must be a Switzerland” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can somebody tell me what the author means here, please?

“The university must be a Switzerland,” he said. “We want every company to collaborate with us and to feel like they have an equal opportunity to hire our students and work with our faculty.”

Source:https://www.seattletimes.com/business/Facebook-opening-new-ai-lab-in-Seattle-as-it-hires-uw-professor/

Comment: It sounds as thought the writer is comparing the institution to the country of Switzerland, which is known for its beauty, efficiency, cleanliness, political neutrality, international trade links and much more.

Comment: And yodeling. Don't forget the yodeling.  Open to (international) business is the gist.

Comment: A "little Switzerland" might be slightly more apt.

Answer (score 1):

The reference here to Switzerland is due to its political neutrality. This can be seen also in the context of equal opportunity.